# Python: how to print detailed error messages about errors?

Tags: python, debugging, exception, error-handling

I'd like to get detailed info about each variable treatment error.

Example 1:

```
user = User()
print(user.name)
...
AttributeError: variable 'user' (class User) doesn't have field 'name', there are only: full_name, address, telephone, email
```

Example 2:

```
some_nums = [1, 2, 3]
print(some_nums[3])
...
IndexError: attempt to get #4 'some_nums' list's elem; it has only 3 elems
```

I known i can wrap each method in my program in individual try-expect block and  print such message in the except clause in each of them.

But it there any way to *collect local variables data*, automatically pass it to top *single* try-except block and print such messages there?

I saw something like in py.test library. It overrides builtin python assert's and prints detailed message in stack trace when assert falls
https://pytest.org/latest/assert.html

Answer (score 1):

You can override the magic method `__getattribute__` if you want to

```
class HelpfulErrors(object):

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        except:
            raise AttributeError("class {} doesn't have field '{}', there are only: {}".format(self.__class__.__name__, name, ", ".join(self.__dict__.keys())))

class User(HelpfulErrors):

    def __init__(self, age=21):
        self.age = age
        self.can_drink = self.age >= 21


u = User()
print(u.age)
print(u.can_drink)
print(u.name)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
21
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mes.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(u.name)
  File "mes.py", line 6, in __getattribute__
    raise AttributeError("class {} doesn't have field '{}', there are only: {}".format(self.__class__.__name__, name, ", ".join(self.__dict__.keys())))
AttributeError: class User doesn't have field 'name', there are only: can_drink, age
```

This really only tells you what is currently in the classes `__dict__` though, so this could change over time unless all instance members that will ever be available are defined by the time `__init__` is finished.

Comment: But it is applicable approach only for my own classes. How about builtin ones?